# GeoServer polygon-grayscale-filter

Tags: geoserver, polygon, sld

Have a colorful wms-layer and a polygon. Want to create layer-group for a wms-service. Under the polygon wms-layer should be gray-scaled. Did some tests with blending (VendorOption) But all I got was negative effect or some weird color-changing. But no gray-scaling.
Alternative to make polygon transparent-gray looks awful, too.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the code, I guess you can prepare a grayed out and a non grayed out version of the base layer, and then use alpha-compositing against the mask to show one or the other (check dst-in, dst-out and src-in/src-out modes).

If you can program in Java, you could build your own custom blending mode and add it to the available ones here:
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/6fb2ecf355d1136e9acd42e18dd129bec238e70c/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/composite/BlendComposite.java

Comment: Nice idea, thx! But I can't get it done: First I got the grayed out version (default raster style). Second I've got the polygon with "destination-in". Now I have a white map with gray map in shape of polygon (gr8!!) But how can I get the color version into the white part? VendorOption does not seem to work for the color version.

Comment: Created own blending mode "dr * 0.299 + dg * 0.587 + db * 0.114". thx!

Comment: If it works well you might as well contribute it to GeoTools, see instructions here: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/procedures/contribute.html